# Reading binary file of integers

Tags: c++, binary, ifstream

First I am writing some int variables to .bin file. Then I try to read those numbers back, but I fail to do that.

This is how I write:

```
std::ofstream OutFile;
OutFile.open("encode.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

for(int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++){
        int code = codes[i];
        OutFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&code), sizeof(int));
}
OutFile.close();
```

And this is how my .bin files looks like when I write numbers: `65, 66, 66, 257, 258, 260`

```
  Offset: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F   
00000000: 41 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 01 01 00 00   
00000010: 02 01 00 00 04 01 00 00
```

Is there a problem with endian? I see that numbers are reversed.

And how I read it:

```
std::vector<int> allCodes;
std::ifstream inputD(file, std::ios::binary);

std::vector<char> buffer((
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inputD)),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

for (auto a : buffer) {
    data.push_back(static_cast<int>(a));
    allCodes.push_back(a);
};
```

When I display my vector first three numbers `(65, 66, 66)` are read correctly, with few zeros in between.

This is how display looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use `reinterpret_cast` here, because of the endianness - you lose portability. You write integers which are **4 bytes** long in your case. Then you try to read the numbers to **char** which has only **1 byte**. This explains why you see correct output for the first three numbers (they are in range from 0 to 255) and why there are some zeros between them.

Here, I found some piece of code on my hard drive, it probably could be written better, but it does the job and is a bit safer than your solution.

```
template<typename T> void ReadInteger(T &Output, const char* Buffer)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, "return type cannot be non-arithmetic or floating point");
    Output = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<sizeof(T); i++)
    {
        Output <<= 8;
        Output |= Buffer[i];
    }
}

template<typename T> void WriteInteger(T Value, char* Buffer)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, "first parameter cannot be non-arithmetic or floating point");
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<sizeof(T); i++)
    {
        Buffer[sizeof(T)-i-1] = static_cast<char>(Value&0xff);
        Value >>= 8;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
int Value = 42;
char Buffer[sizeof(int)];
WriteInteger(Value, Buffer);
File.write(Buffer, sizeof(int));
// ...
File.read(Buffer, sizeof(int));
int a;
ReadInteger(a, Buffer);
```

Comment: thank, that helped. How could I iterate through file and get all the numbers back? Would istream_iterator<int> work?

Comment: @mihcc AFAIK in this case it's not possible to use `istream_iterator<int>`. To do so, you would need to write formatted output (separated by whitespaces for example) instead of packing the integers. To iterate through the whole file you can do these steps: make a loop which begins with `File.read(...)` then check if `File` has `EOF` flag set, if so, break the loop, otherwise process the data.